# unable to locate packages despite having added the repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04

I ran

```
# apt install -y libexpect-perl libstring-random-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libexpect-perl
E: Unable to locate package libstring-random-perl
```

so following the standard advice, I tried to add the *universe* repository.

```
# add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

and the `apt install` command still failed.  This is on 20.04.  What next?

OBTW, the machine is physically remote and I have only `ssh` access so no GUI answers please.

As per comment and answer I tried:

```
root@mytim:~# add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
root@mytim:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                      
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease                                        
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
14 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@mytim:~# apt install libexpect-perl libstring-random-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libexpect-perl
E: Unable to locate package libstring-random-perl
```

Comment: what does apt search libexpect-perl  give you ? does it see an installeable version available ?

Comment: maybe the packages are corrupted somehow, doing apt clean should remove all compressed packages and then your install would retrieve the package remotely once more and would install properly.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't finish adding universe repository packages to your software sources because you also need to update the list of available software with `sudo apt update`. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libexpect-perl libstring-random-perl
```

Comment: Thanks;  I've done that and repeated the `apt` commands, and appended a transcript to my OP.

Comment: According to the most recent appended transcript to the question the universe repository is added to your software sources, but the software sources are still not being updated from the universe repository. Maybe there is some kind of a problem with your update server mirror. That the machine is physically remote may also have something to do with the cause of this problem connecting to the universe repository.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `diff -qr` on the */etc/apt* directories of the the misbehaving PC and one that is working and they were significantly different.  The PCs are located remotely and are subject to adverse conditions such as having the power pulled rather than being shut down properly.

So I'm putting this down to that.  Thanks all for the contributions but I reckon this is down to a corrupt apt data-set.